# Synergy Between Windows Vista and 7 fails. 

Tags: synergy

My Synergy line up is a Windows 7 Home Premium PC (wired to wireless router) to the left of my Windows Vista Home Premium HP Notebook (wireless to wireless router)

On my Vista notebook the client works (I don't get a message).

On my Windows 7 computer the host doesn't work. I get the following message:

> Failed to save autostart configuration: Access denied

What can I do to get Synergy working?

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google came up with these solutions: http://code.google.com/p/synergy-plus/issues/detail?id=256

It would appear that running the program as administrator and configuring the auto start options or manually creating the config files offer a fix.

Any good to you?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the bug report cited by @moif-murphy at http://code.google.com/p/synergy-plus/issues/detail?id=256 now has a workaround:

Delete the Autorun key

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\Synergy Server
```

in the windows registry, no admin account should be necessary if you created the Autorun setting yourself before.